# edit crowd.server.url on confluence to access jira directory (crowd)

Tags: jira, confluence, atlassian-crowd

We have Jira and Confluence hosted external (no direct server access) behind an Apache. Our confluence uses the Jira logins via Atlassian crowd.
We wanted to secure our production Jira with SSL. As soon as we add a forward rule so all http-request will be forwarded to https, we are no longer able to login to confluence. So we temporarily let this forwarding be disabled again.

We found that in confluence-administration at user-directories there is an overview showing `"crowd.server.url": "http://<our-jira-url>"`, so we guessed this is the culprit. But we found nowhere a posibility to edit this value. Neither in confluence-administration nor is there a `crowd.properties` file found in the server-paths (installation and application-data) we have access to.

Can someone please tell what and how should I configure confluence to being able to access our jira-user-directory via https?

Answer (score 2):

Found it. You must change the value for internal Crowd (or JIRA) server URL:

```
mysql> use confluence;
mysql> update cwd_directory_attribute
    set attribute_value = 'https://your.new.jira.tld/'
    where attribute_name = 'crowd.server.url';
```

After updating, restart Confluence.

Comment: Hi, this worked for me in Confluence, but JIRA is updating that field back to the previous value. Any ideas? Ty.

Comment: @AlexPi, I would try to delete the Application Link between JIRA and Confluence and create it again. But I'm not sure if it's related.

If you have a paid license, contact Atlassian Support here: https://support.atlassian.com/contact/ They are amazing.

Comment: For Jira I used https then I observed previous url sever was just http. I changed it to http and Jira stopped going back to the previous url. Weird. Ty.